# How to build query with selecting by value of foreign object's field

Tags: java, android, ormlite, query-builder

What is the best way for querying by using the value of foreign object's field?

Suppose I have these three classes.

UnitResult class which describes amount of Units:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class UnitResult {
    public static final String ID_FIELD_NAME = "id";
    public static final String UNIT_COLUMN_NAME = "unit";
    public static final String RESULT_COLUMN_NAME = "result";

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = ID_FIELD_NAME)
    public Integer id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, canBeNull = false, columnName = UNIT_COLUMN_NAME)
    public Unit unit;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, columnName = RESULT_COLUMN_NAME)
    public Integer result = null;
}
```

Unit class which describes certain Units in a market (for example jiuce, snack etc.):

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Unit {
    public static final String ID_FIELD_NAME = "id";
    public static final String TYPE_FIELD_NAME = "type";

    @DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = ID_FIELD_NAME)
    public int id;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = TYPE_FIELD_NAME)
    public UnitType type;
}
```

And Enum of Unit type:

```
public enum UnitType {
    JUICES,
    DRINKS,
    SNACKS,
    NPD;
}
```

So how can I query all `UnitResult` where `Unit` type is `UnitType.JUICES`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> So how can I query all UnitResult where Unit type is UnitType.JUICES?

The way to do this in [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) is to use the [`Where.in(...) with a sub-query](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html#in%28java.lang.String,%20com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder%29):

```
// setup our sub-query on the Unit table first
QueryBuilder<Unit,Integer> uQb = unitDao.queryBuilder();
uQb.where().eq(Unit.TYPE_FIELD_NAME, UnitType.JUICES);
// outer query on UnitResult table
QueryBuilder<UnitResult,Integer> urQb = unitResultDao.queryBuilder();
// in using the sub-query
urQb.where().in(UnitResult.UNIT_COLUMN_NAME, uQb);
List<UnitResult> results = urQb.query();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Gray! And respect for OrmLite library! :)

Comment: This no longer seems to work.  Because the id column is automagically added to the query, it throws "SQLException, Inner query must have only 1 select column specified instead of *".

Comment: Followup: I believe the intent is that you now use a join.