# Trying write a query with ORMLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I'm trying write a query using ORMLite. I need this query check a id of customer in other entity. How could I do it ?

**Entities**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "customer")
public class Customer {
     
      @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
      private Integer id;

      @DatabaseField
      private String name;

      @DatabaseField
      private Sale sale;

      //gets sets
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "sale")
public class Sale{
     
      @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
      private Integer id;

      @DatabaseField
      private Customer customer;

      @DatabaseField
      private Integer status;

      //gets sets
}
```

**Query**

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setId(1);
customer.setName("Fernando Paiva");

QueryBuilder<Sale, Integer> qb = saleDAO.queryBuilder();
            Where where = qb.where();
            where.eq("sale.customer.id", customer.getId());
            where.and();
            where.eq("sale.status", 1);
            PreparedQuery<Sale> pq = qb.prepare();
            List<Sale> list = saleDAO.query(pq);
            Log.i("SALE LIST->", list.size() + "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [JOIN](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html#Join-Queries)

Here your example using Join:

1. First of all, you need a QueryBuilder to each Dao.
2. You can apply your filter to each QueryBuilder separately
3. Last but not least, you join the main QueryBuilder (Sales) with the Customer's QueryBuilder and
4. perform the query.

Here the code

```
Dao<Sale, Integer> saleDao = DaoManager.createDao(getConnectionSource(), Sale.class);
Dao<Customer, Integer> customerDao = DaoManager.createDao(getConnectionSource(), Customer.class);

QueryBuilder<Sale, Integer> saleQa= saleDao.queryBuilder();
saleQa.where().eq("status", 1);
QueryBuilder<Customer, Integer> customerQa = customerDao.queryBuilder();
customerQa.where().idEq(customer.getId());

sales = saleQa.join(customerQa).query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use OrmLite to check if the customer id is the same as the sale id and get all of the matching result? If so the below code will do that

```
qb.where().eq("id", customer.id);
List<Sale> results = saleDAO.query(qb.prepare());
```

Update:

After rereading your question I realized what you're trying to do

```
qb.where().in(Sale.customer, id);
```

See this question for further details.
[Ormlite Foreign Entity Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118350/how-to-build-query-with-selecting-by-value-of-foreign-objects-field)