# Writing a query with ORMLite search by column

Tags: android, ormlite

I have to column User and MyDream. I need create query with OrmLite with dispaly my_dream by firebase_id.
This my sql query

select my_dream_id, title_dream,descryption_dream,saveDataDream from MyDream,User where User.user_id = MyDream.user_user_id and User.firebaseId='56789'

I don't idea have write query in Java

[image: column database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to define your classes:

```
public class User {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private Integer user_id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String email;
    @DatabaseField
    private Integer firebase_id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String fullname;
    @DatabaseField
    private String photo_url;
    @ForeignCollectionField
    private LazyForeignCollection<Dream, Integer> dreams;
}

public class Dream {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private Integer my_dream_id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String description_dream;
    @DatabaseField
    private ?? saveDataDream;
    @DatabaseField
    private String titleDream;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "user_user_id", foreign = true)
    private User user;
}
```

Then, as I've asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033931/trying-write-a-query-with-ormlite/46290530#46290530), you need to use [Join](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html#Join-Queries) to query the results

Its the same explanation, but here is the code to your example

```
Dao<User, Integer> userDao = DaoManager.createDao(getConnectionSource(), User.class);
Dao<Dream, Integer> dreamDao = DaoManager.createDao(getConnectionSource(), Dream.class);

QueryBuilder<User, Integer> userQa= userDao.queryBuilder();
userQa.where().eq("firebaseId", 56789);
QueryBuilder<Dream, Integer> dreamQa = dreamDao.queryBuilder();

users = userQa.join(dreamQa).query();
```

Then you can access dreams from User's object `users.get(i).getDreams()` using `iterator()`, like this:

```
CloseableIterator<Dream> itDream = users.get(id).getDreams().closeableIterator();
try {
    while (itDream.hasNext()) {
        Dream dream = itDream.next();
    }
} finally {
    try {
        itDream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "FAIL", e);
    }
}
```